# Dialog fragment throwing exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-service, android-dialogfragment

I have an activity that is receiving some Integers from a service. When a certain Integer is received, the Activity calls a dialog fragment and displays a dialog box. My App works perfectly fine while the activity is in the foreground. When it is in the background, such as being paused, and the service sends an integer that would cause a dialog fragment to appear, I get an exception

```
IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

I know this is because the activity is paused and trying to call a dialog fragment would cause a state loss. How can I get my app to not crash, but still display the activity and dialog box when it is reopened?

i use a handler to receive the Integer form the service

```
if (msg.arg1 > 7) 
                {
                    DialogFragment dialog = new YesNoDialog();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("title", "Warning");
                    args.putString("message", "Threshold has been reached");
                    dialog.setArguments(args);
                    //dialog.setTargetFragment(this, YES_NO_CALL);
                    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
                }
```

So i would like this code to execute and let the user know this has happened even when the app is paused, and when the app is reopened a dialog box will appear. My alertdialog is supposed to call some methods from the main activity such as

```
.setNegativeButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                //getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
                ((MyActivity)getActivity()).onContinueClick();
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton("Stop", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                //getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, null);
                ((MyActivity)getActivity()).onStopClick();
            }
        })
```

It all works perfectly, except for when the MyActivity activity is in the the background.

Comment: In your display dialog, test for a boolean that you set/unset in onSaveInstanceState

Comment: How do you receive the integer from the service? Plus post some code so we can help you precisely.

Comment: If the boolean is true, then onSaveInstance state would have been called, if it is false, my OnCreate or onResume would have been called. I understand that the boolean could be used to check what state the app is in, but I want to display the dialog box either way, not only when the app is in the foreground. How can a boolean accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there's no guarantee that your activity will still exist when the service sends messages back, because it might have been destroyed, you would be better off having the service create a [notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) which when clicked starts an activity that shows your dialog.

An alternative is for the service to store the message in shared preferences, then broadcast an intent that indicates a message is ready. The activity would be listening for these broadcasts while it's running, show the dialog and remove the message from shared preferences. Every time the activity is created or resumed, you would check for the message and do the same (because the broadcast intent is lost if there are no listeners).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My dialog is meant to stop a sound that is supposed to start when the specific integer is received from the sound. I know this can be done with a notification as well. I'm just afraid the user will not know to use the notification to stop the sound. I guess I could implement an alarm button that would stop any sounds playing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you need the notification to be immediate, like an alarm clock? From the service, try starting a new activity that shows the dialog. That way you don't rely on the old activity still being present.